# Testing PUT method in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, testing, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to test a PUT method in django rest framework. I get HttpResponsePermanentRedirect instead of response object. My views for a put method are set to send status 200 after successful update. Error:

> self.assertEqual(response.data, serializer.data)
>   AttributeError: 'HttpResponsePermanentRedirect' object has no attribute 'data'

tests.py

```
class PostTestGetAndPutMethod(APITestCase):
    def setup(self):
        Post.objects.create(title="POST CREATED", content="POST WAS CREATED")
        Post.objects.create(title="POST CREATED 2", content="POST WAS CREATED 2")
        Post.objects.create(title="POST CREATED 3", content="POST WAS CREATED 3")

    def test_get_posts(self):
        '''
        Ensure we can get list of posts
        '''
        # get API response 
        response = self.client.get(reverse('posts'))
        # get data from DB
        posts = Post.objects.all()
        # convert it to JSON
        serializer = PostSerializer(posts, many=True)
        # check the status 
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
        self.assertEqual(response.data, serializer.data)

    def test_update_put_post(self):
        '''
        Check if we can update post 
        '''
        data = {'title': 'POST MODIFIED', 'content': 'CONTENT MODIFIED'}
        response = self.client.put('/posts/1', data)
        serializer = PostSerializer(data)
        self.assertEqual(response.data, serializer.data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

views.py

```
@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def post_detail(request, pk):
    """
    Retrieve, update or delete a code snippet.
    """
    try:
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Post.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = PostSerializer(post)
        return Response(data=serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer = PostSerializer(post, data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        post.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

**EDIT**
test should look like this:

```
class PostTestPutMethod(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # Posts to be modified 
        self.first_post = Post.objects.create(title="POST CREATED", content="POST WAS CREATED")
        self.second_post = Post.objects.create(title="POST CREATED 2", content="POST WAS CREATED 2")

        self.valid_post = {
            "title" : "post is changed",
            "content": "post is changed"
        }
        self.invalid_post = {
            "title": "",
            "content": "post change"
        }
    def test_valid_update_post(self):
        '''
        Validated data case 
        '''
        response = self.client.put(
            reverse('post_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.first_post.pk}),
            data = json.dumps(self.valid_post),
            content_type = 'application/json'
        )
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def test_invalid_update_post(self):
        '''
        Invalid data case 
        '''
        response = self.client.put(
            reverse('post_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.second_post.pk}),
            data = json.dumps(self.invalid_post),
            content_type = 'application/json'
        )
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Also there is small mistake right here in views:
`serializer = PostSerializer(post, data=data)`
and should be replaced with 
`serializer = PostSerializer(post, data=request.data)`

Comment: Note, your view does not allow creation: you'll be given a 404 response.

Answer (score 2):

In the first test, you nailed it:

```
response = self.client.get(reverse('posts'))
```

Next up, you hard code the path, missing the slash at the end.

```
response = self.client.put('/posts/1', data)
```

Django will then try to redirect **/posts/1** to **/posts/1/**. Add a slash or find the correct name for reverse() in the test, and you should be good.

Also, I can really recommend using DRF generic views. Less code, more sanity checks: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/

Comment: Note that you can disable this behavior in Django by using `APPEND_SLASH = False` in your settings.